# Followship ogranization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models, relationship

I'm sitting here thinking about how I would organize the following scenario:

1. User can follow users and vice versa
2. User can follow groups but **NOT** vice versa
3. User can follow posts but **NOT** vice versa

Should it be enough with a `Followship` model to store all relations or should I split it into several models? The feed will display entries and comments from all of these.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you might be best off with polymorphic associations in this case [polymorphism activity feed](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/using-polymorphism-to-make-a-better-activity-feed-in-rails)

Comment: Yeah for the feed that's a good idea but what's your thoughts about the followship relations?

Comment: personally I think I would probably try setting up a linking table 'Followship' which would have polymorphic associations to the 'follower' and the 'followed'

Answer (score 0):

Before reinventing the wheel, please check out the [socialization gem](https://github.com/cmer/socialization).

If you dont want to use the gem, take a look at the source as the gem is very comprehensive in terms of following, liking, and mentioning.